# Почему нестатические поля и блоки инициализируются раньше конструктора класса?

Tags: java

Ведь конструктор и занимается инициализированием нестатических полей класса. Но везде пишут, что нестатические поля и блоки инициализируются раньше конструктора. Как так?

Comment: Вот здесь неплохо про инициализацию поясняют http://www.quizful.net/post/java-fields-initialization

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем так.

У нас есть конструктор по умолчанию:

```
Joestar(){
//Код
}
```

Мы идём в метод main и запускаем его:

```
Joestar jotaro = new Joestar();
```

Всё. Конструктор запущен. Теперь он начинает работу:

Поехали.

1) Программа проверяет есть ли в первой строчке тела конструктора (т.е. между "{ }") конструкции **this**() и **super**(). Кажется, что в нашем случае ни первой, ни второй нет, однако на самом деле JVM всё-равно вызывает неявный конструктор суперкласса super() (если у класса, объект которого мы создаём, нет класса-родителя, то вызываться будет конструктор класса **Object**, который возвращает пустое значение(т.е. ничего не делает. Вообще)). (Если этот пункт не очень понятен - можно его пока пропустить).

2) Далее, происходит инициализация нестатических полей **объекта (не класса!)** и нестатического блока инициализации (если он есть);

3) Выполняется код в теле конструктора.

4) Объект создан. Теперь ему присваивается переменная Jotaro.

Запомните, нестатических полей **класса** не существует в природе. Все нестатические поля - это поля конкретного **объекта**.

```
class Joestar
   float height;
   String name;
   int age;
   String stand;
   static int joestarFamilyMembersCount = 1;
```

Полей **height**, **name**, **age** и **stand** не существует, пока не создан хотя бы один объект класса Joestar, а когда он будет создан, эти переменные будут жить **только внутри него** и сослаться на них можно будет тоже только через него.

Answer (score 0):

Неплохо обобщить знания о процессе создания объекта. Для примера возьмем класс с именем Dog:

□ Хотя ключевое слово static и не используется явно, конструктор в действительности является статическим методом. При создании первого объекта типа Dog или при первом вызове статического метода/обращения к статическому полю класса Dog интерпретатор Java должен найти класс Dog.class. Поиск осуществляется в стандартных каталогах, перечисленных в переменной окружения CLASSPATH.

□ После загрузки файла Dog.class производится инициализация статических элементов. Таким образам, инициализация статических членов проводится только один раз, при первой загрузке объекта Class.

□ При создании нового объекта конструкцией new Dog() для начала выделяется блок памяти, достаточный для хранения объекта Dog в куче.

□ Выделенная память заполняется нулями, при этом все примитивные поля объекта Dog автоматически инициализируются значениями по умолчанию (ноль для чисел, его эквиваленты для типов boolean и char, null для ссылок).

□ Выполняются все действия по инициализации, происходящие в точке определения полей класса.

□ Выполняются конструкторы.